# Contribution Widgets

Tags: civicontribute, widget

Is anyone doing any work on Contribution widgets?  We use them all the time, but they have problems on our end - specifically they do not update immediately when new donations are made - we have to personally clear browser cookies in order to see updated information. (this is likely a local issue - not civicrm)

Is anyone working on a Contribution Widget plugin for core or wordpress (our current setup) - paid or otherwise? Something more visually appealing or dynamic than what we have now?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a plugin that makes embedding the widgets easier: https://wordpress.org/plugins/civicrm-contribution-page-widget/. But I'm guessing it may not meet your 'nicer looking' requirement as it is just using what widget settings you have but I started using this when I started having issues using the code snippet.

Working fine on my instances.

Comment: Yeah - we don't use that as you can't edit the code.  We simply use the customized code and use the Shortcoder plugin to embed it on pages. Using the shortcoder plugin makes sure that the code doesnt get messed up when switching from Visual to text...

Comment: On another note, does your progress automatically update without issue?

Comment: Yeah, I have never had an issue with the updates.